# jquery fancybox at the top left of the page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

The website is : [www.prodevcoind.com/pcr42/](http://www.prodevcoind.com/pcr42/)

Fancybox is showing really bad when you click on a image.

The fancybox is small at the top left.

Anyone can give me a clue?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a fancybox **js** file **[v2.1.5](http://www.prodevcoind.com/wp-content/themes/nemo/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-2.1.5.pack.js)** BUT with a fancybox **css** file **[v1.3.4](http://www.prodevcoind.com/wp-content/themes/nemo/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css)**

Since fancybox (v2.1.5) doesn't find the proper css selectors it uses its default minimum size of 100px and it's completely "style-less"

**EDIT** (Nov 1st, 2013): OP commented:

```
Now, with the correct css file, it<s better 
but still at the top left of the page
```

***Explanation*** :

You have this css rul in your [global](http://www.prodevcoind.com/wp-content/themes/nemo/styles/global.css) css file :

```
html * {
  border: 0 none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed','RobotoRegular';
  font-weight: normal !important;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0 none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Which sets a `margin: 0;` to **all** of the *html* descendants (including fancybox), this is why the fancybox is at the top left of the screen (all margins are set to `0`)

Normally, it's NOT a good idea to edit the original files from a plugin (they will those changes lost if you upgrade, most likely you will) but change they behavior through your custom css or js files

Comment: Doh! What a newbie error. Now, with the correct css file, it<s better but still at the top left of the page, not at the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the height for the fancybox div is 100px. Try editing the height via "Inspect Element" in Google Chrome or "Firebug" in Firefox and see how it fixes your issue. After doing so, try editing it in the code.

Comment: Fancybox isn't suppose to make this value by itself?

Comment: It's better but now, the overlay isn't displaying correcly.

Answer (score 0):

in your css file http://www.prodevcoind.com/wp-content/themes/nemo/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-2.1.5.css?ver=1.0

find

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and replace it with

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
left: 25%;
top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: it's better but now the overlay isn't diplaying correcly. The overlay doesn't cover all the area.

Comment: I've put your tips elsewhere. I changed this instead and leave ".fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay" like it was.

.fancybox-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 8020;
 left: 25% !important;
 top: 10% !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

find

`.fancybox-wrap {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 8020;
    }`

and replace it with

`.fancybox-wrap {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 8020;
        left: 25% !important;
        top: 10% !important;
    }`

Comment: Normally, it's NOT a good idea to edit the original files from a plugin (they will lost those changes if you upgrade, most likely you will) but change they behavior through your custom css or js files. See my edited answer why your fancybox was a the top left of the screen